# Need help passing arguments via Buildr

Tags: buildr

I am a newbie to Buildr(Apache Buildr), I am trying to run a junit test using buildr but I am not sure how to pass the arguments like -Djava.awt.headless=true etc..

I tried something like below, but doesn't seem to work

```
  test.using( :java_args => ['-Djava.awt.headless:true'])
```

I am not sure if I need to pass this to system properties or JVM arguments, can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the right way but there's a small typo in your `:java_args`, it should be:

```rb
test.using :java_args => [ '-Djava.awt.headless=true' ]
```

(notice the equal sign after `headless` versus a colon in your question.)

There is also a more concise/foolproof way of passing `properties` using a hash of property names and values,

```rb
test.using :properties => { "java.awt.headless" => "true" }
```